# Desenvolvimento de APIs com Laravel ou Micro Frameworks?

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

Boa noite!
Depois de analisar o meu projeto decidi dividir todo o projeto em APIs, vai ter uma api para o login, outra para cadastro de clientes e assim sucessivamente. Ai bate a tal da duvida sera que o laravel é a melhor opção para o desenvolvimento de APIs? Li em alguns artigos que a melhor opção para estes cados é a utilização de micro frameworks como o Zend Expressive qual é a experiencia de vocês sobre isso?

Obrigado

Comment: Na minha experiência, se é pra usar PHP, o "sem nada" é o melhor framework. Geralmente "extras" de terceiros só complicam as camadas. Principalmente pra APIs, que quanto mais independência, mais fácil a manutenção. A maior prova de que FW em PHP geralmente é má idéia é o próprio código que você encontra na web feito com eles. Muita gente adota por não dominar programação e achar que o FW vai facilitar a vida (e o código produzido continua tosco). Até existe uma parcela que sabe usar FW em PHP e justamente usa em casos pontuais, mas está longe de ser maioria (e esses acabam fazendo um próprio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particularmente eu gosto muito mais da ideia de utilizar micro-frameworks, não vejo motivos para utilizar um framework tão grande e complexo que de certa forma causa um peso extra e mais complexidade em minhas aplicações sendo que existem soluções muito mais simples e limpas, um exemplo dentro do PHP é o micro-framework Flight que tem como finalidade justamente a construção de API´s, com quase nenhuma configuração e pouquíssimas linhas de código você já tem sua primeira rota funcional.

Em resumo recomendo muito a ideia de ir utilizando micro-frameworks e ir os somando a medida que o projeto cresce, esses frameworks maiores eu só partiria os utilizando se eu já visse no inicio do projeto que ele seria muito grande e complexo.

Link do micro-framework:
http://flightphp.com/